# weak convergence and compactness

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, parabolic-pde

please how can I prove that if a sequence $u_n \to  u$ in $L^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^+; H^1(\Omega)) $ weak * and $\partial_t u_n \to \partial_t u$ in $L^2(0,T, L^2(\Omega)) $ weak for all $T>0$ implies  that $u_n \to  u$ in $L^2(0,T,L^2(\Omega))$ strong for all $T>0$.

Answer (score 1):

Since weakly convergent sequences are norm bounded in the respective space, we have in particular

$$\|u_n\|_{L^2(0,T;H^1)}, \|\partial_t u_n\|_{L^2 (H^1)'} \leq C$$

hence by the [Aubin--Lions lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aubin%E2%80%93Lions_lemma) you get that $u_n \to u$ in $L^2(0,T;L^2)$ strongly. For the proof I refer you to the [paper by Jacques Simon](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01762360). Alternatively, you can look at the [book from Boyer and Fabrie](https://www.springer.com/de/book/9781461459743).

Comment: Please I have a question why $u_n$ is bonded in $L^2(H^1)$?

Comment: @RomeissaRachi Weak * convergence in $L^\infty$ implies weak convergence in $L^p$ for any $p> 1$ (see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170403/weak-convergence-and-weak-star-convergence) . Now you may make use of Fritz's answer.