# Definition of weak* convergence in $L^{\infty}$

Tags: functional-analysis, lp-spaces, weak-convergence

I'm new to functional analysis and have (what I think is) a basic question on the definition of weak* convergence.

Let $X$ be a normed linear space with dual $X^{\ast}$. According to the definition I know, a sequence $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in  $X^{\ast}$ is said to converge weakly* to $f \in X^{\ast}$ if $f_n$ converges pointwise to $f$, that is, if
$$\forall x \in X, \quad\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} f_n(x) = f(x).$$

In the special case that $X^{\ast} = L^{\infty}(\Omega,\mu)$ for some measure space $(\Omega,\mathcal{A},\mu)$, I've stumpled upon a different definition (for example, [here](https://www.uio.no/studier/emner/matnat/math/MAT4380/v06/Weakconvergence.pdf) and [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/170403/weak-convergence-and-weak-star-convergence)): a sequence $(f_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ in $L^{\infty}(\Omega,\mu)$ converges weakly* to $f \in L^{\infty}(\Omega,\mu)$ if
$$\forall g \in L^1(\Omega,\mu), \quad \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_{\Omega} f_n g \,\text{d}\mu = \int_{\Omega} f g \,\text{d}\mu.$$

My feeling is that both definitions are equivalent because of Riesz' Representation Theorem. Is this correct? If so, how can the equivalence be formally proved?

Comment: If $\mu$ is $\sigma$--finite then $L_1^*=L_\infty$, Otherwise things become a little more complicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not the Riesz Representation Theorem, but one can show without a lot of effort that for sigma-finite measures the dual of $L^1(\Omega)$ can be identified with $L^\infty(\Omega)$ with the natural duality that makes $f\in L^\infty$ a linear functional on $L^1$ via
$$
g\longmapsto \int_\Omega fg.
$$

Comment: Ok, thanks, the identification of $(L^1)^{\ast}$ with $L^{\infty}$ is precisely what I had in mind. Royden and Fitzpatrick (2010, Real Analysis, 4th ed, p. 400) call this the "Riesz Representation Theorem for the dual of $L^p(X,\mu)$''.

Comment: Fair enough. Doesn't seem to be the [common use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riesz_representation_theorem), though, where the name is reserved for the case $p=2$.